# Proving $1-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)=\frac{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}{\sin x+\cos x}$ without factoring

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a way to prove this identity without factoring?

$$1-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)=\frac{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}{\sin x+\cos x}$$

Comment: @CalvinLin Do you mean it should be $\sin^3x+\cos^3x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $$1-\frac12\sin2x=1-\sin x\cos x=\sin^2x+\cos^2x-\sin x\cos x$$ by double-angle formula and Pythagorean identity. To show that this is equal to the desired right-hand side, note that the desired right-hand side is defined so long as $\sin x+\cos x\neq 0$, and in such a case, we have $$\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}=1.$$ Multiply $\sin^2x+\cos^2x-\sin x\cos x$ by this, and simplify the numerator.

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l}\frac{{{{\sin }^3}x + {{\cos }^3}x}}{{\sin x + \cos x}} = \frac{{\left( {\sin x + \cos x} \right)\left( {{{\sin }^2}x - \sin x\cos x + {{\cos }^2}x} \right)}}{{\sin x + \cos x}}\\ = 1 - \sin x\cos x = 1 - \frac{1}{2}\left( {2\sin x\cos x} \right) = 1 - \sin 2x\end{array}$$

Comment: I'm not sure of the purpose of your comment....

Comment: Your answer is complete and perfect. I just wanted to mention that how the factor $\sin^2x+\cos^2x-\sin x\cos x$ can be found; since I think it is not so easy to understand how this factor is found without expanding the $\sin^3x+\cos^3x$.

Comment: If you find my comment to be irrelevant; please tell me to just delete it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the identity should be
$$1-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x=\frac{\cos^3 x+\sin^3 x}{\sin x+\cos x}.$$
If you don't want to factor, just multiply the denominator on both sides, and do multiplication.

Comment: Thank you, someone asked me the question and guess he copied it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Motivated by the fact that $(a^2 + b^2 - ab)(a+b) =a^3 + b^3$, we see LHS = $1 - \frac{1}{2} \sin(2x) = \sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2 - \sin(x) \cos(x)$ and we are done.